# Making Leaflet image overlay draggable?

Tags: leaflet, imagery

I simply want to make a georeferenced imageOverlay draggable in leaflet.
I found several unanswered posts (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688057/leaflet-overlay-image-dragging-and-resizing) and [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3883)).

Since it is easy to make markers draggable, someone tried to adapt the code for imageOverlay [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2564). The issue was closed and refered to the [interactive option for events on imageOverlays.](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3009/commits/ca2f1171b7e325434a78696a32d2d537419af0b9)

According to the last two links, it shouldn't be so difficult but I have no idea how to do it - do you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple workaround is to bind the imageOverlay to a draggable Polygon (thanks to **w8r** for this idea, developer of Leaflet.Path.Drag)

```
 var poly1 = [
    [40.71222, -74.22655],
    [40.77394, -74.22655],
    [40.77394, -74.12544],
    [40.71222, -74.12544]
 ];
 var pg = new L.Polygon([poly1],{
       draggable: true,
       opacity: 0,
       fillOpacity: 0
    }).addTo(map);  

 var imageBounds = L.latLngBounds([
    poly1[0],
    poly1[2]
 ]);
 map.fitBounds(imageBounds);
 var overlay = new L.ImageOverlay("https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg", imageBounds, {
    opacity: 0.7,
    interactive: true
 });
 map.addLayer(overlay);

 pg.on('drag, dragend', function (e) {
    overlay.setBounds(pg.getBounds());
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/freeze2000f/e2co5jv0/

Comment: It is not clear in your answer that you need to install a pllugin for this..

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through some more answers and found this nice stuff.

Here it is: https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.