# Dragging and dropping images into Leaflet map to create image markers?

Tags: leaflet, icon, html5

I am using Leaflet. I need to make custom, draggable, resizable icons for the map, using custom images that are set inside a sidebar as such:

```
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div class="dropdown">Actions
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <img src="Symboles\Actions\Actions Défensives\def_lig.png" alt="def lig" title="def lig" class="dragger"><p>Défense en ligne</p></img>
                <img src="Symboles\Actions\Actions Défensives\def_lig_pre.png" alt="def lig pre" title="def lig pre" class="dragger"><p>Défense en ligne prévue</p></img>
                <img src="Symboles\Actions\Actions Défensives\def_prm.png" alt="def prm" title="def prm" class="dragger"><p>Défense périmétrique</p></img>
                <img src="Symboles\Actions\Actions Défensives\def_prm_pre.png" alt="def prm pre" title="def prm pre" class="dragger"><p>Défense périmétrique prévue</p></img>
                <img src="Symboles\Actions\Actions offensives\act_loc_inde.png" alt="act loc inde" title="act loc inde" class="dragger"><p>Action localisée indépendante</p></img>
                <img src="Symboles\Actions\Actions offensives\act_noria.png" alt="act noria" title="act noria" class="dragger"><p>Action en Noria</p></img>
                <img src="Symboles\Actions\Actions offensives\act_smlt_cct.png" alt="act smlt cct" title="act smlt cct" class="dragger"><p>Action simultanée et concertée</p></img>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I know I have to use `L.icons` But I have no idea on how to do it with my sidebar, since it'll have about 100 images.

Comment: Are you sure you want `L.Icon`? I'm testing around a bit here and `L.Icon` doesn't change its size when you change the zoom level. From the given image descriptions it rather looks as if you were looking for [`ImageOverlay`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#imageoverlay). Can you confirm?

Comment: ImageOverlay ? never heard/seen that one before

Comment: That's not the question. ;-) What do you want to achieve? A marker that stays the same size no matter the underlying map and its zoom level? Or an image that fits some geographic bounds? :) PS.: Haven't used `ImageOverlay` either, but it looks promising.

Comment: I want my image to be integrated to the map, and can be dragged around and resizable (I can already drag and rezise them, but they're not in the map) PS : and yes, ImageOverlay looks promising :)

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone you cans use `iconSize` to change the size of the icon ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) you can drag an image from the sidebar and drop it onto the map. For this you will have to bind two listener functions to the map container:

```js
mapdiv = document.getElementById("map")

mapdiv.ondragover = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"
}

mapdiv.ondrop = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  imagePath = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain")
  coordinates = map.containerPointToLatLng(L.point([e.clientX,e.clientY]))
  L.marker(coordinates,{icon: L.icon({iconUrl: imagePath}),
                        draggable: true})
    .addTo(map)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/430oz1pj/197/

`ondragover` has to exist, but we just define the default behaviour. `ondrop` is the important part for your question. Luckily the [drop event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop) comes with some coordinates (`clientX`,`clientY`) that we can pass on to the Leaflet map to create a marker.

Note that this only works correctly if the whole map is visible in the viewport (browser window).

PS.: Markers don't change their size when you zoom the map. That's why I suggested an [`imageOverlay`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#imageoverlay) in the comments. Unfortunately these aren't draggable by default, but you can workaround it by binding them to draggable polygons as described in [this gis.se answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/209466/122597).

Comment: If you like, besides marking it as a solution you can upvote it. This is better than posting thanks as a comment. :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote :(

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this limitation. Then it's fine. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: That's totally fine :)
Now, time to make these  icons resizable and spinnable, since the script I had don't work for them...

Comment: @Stefan I know this is an old question but I notice the first time I drop the image it shifts (down and left). Can that be avoided? Thanks, Mike

Comment: The top-left corner of the image is placed on the coordinates of the cursor. You can subtract half the height and width of the image from the x and y coordinates, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

For those who're straggling with the incorrect location of the marker after drag and drop an img on the map(addition to the previous comment):

```
const val = target.getBoundingClientRect(); 

const { x, y } = val;

[e.clientX-x, e.clientY-y]
```